# Memory Access violation while generating std::vector from C# unmanaged pointer

Tags: c#, c++

The problem I am facing is that I (occasionally) experienced a System.AccessViolationException when I tried to create a `std::vector` from unmanaged pointer to buffer of Bytes in C#.

[image: Windows event log]

### C#

```cs
    WriteableBitmap frameWriteableBitmap = image.RenderImage(0).As<WriteableBitmap>();
    unsafe
    {    
        FormatConvertedBitmap newFormatedBitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap(frameWriteableBitmap, PixelFormats.Rgb24, null, 0);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapSource)newFormatedBitmapSource);
        IntPtr pBackBuffer = wb.BackBuffer;
        byte* pBuff = (byte*)pBackBuffer.ToPointer();

        int stride = (int)((wb.Width * wb.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8);
        int bufferSize = (int)(wb.Height * stride);

        Detector.setImageToDetection(pBuff, bufferSize);
    }
```

### C++

```cpp
void setImageToDetection(unsigned char* rawData, int num)
{

    std::vector<unsigned char> rawDataVec(rawData, rawData + num);
    image.myRawData = rawDataVec;
   
    //...
}
```

What could be the problem here? It is happening only sometimes (in runtime), but always in Release build (maybe release code optimization has something to do with it?). The size of buffer seems to be computed correctly.

I would appreciate also tips to debug this.

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Does it happen on a single machine ?

Comment: There is always the possibility that C# (or better its garbage collector) will move memory around and C++ will not know about this. I've never done interop like you do, I always used C++/clr. (https://www.codeguru.com/cplusplus/introduction-to-c-cli-programming/). But what I think might also help is if you pin the memory in C# with fixed keyword befor making the call to C++ (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/fixed-statement)

Comment: Is `stride` equal to `wb.BackBufferStride`?

Comment: Also, `wb.Width` is in "device-independent units". You want `wb.PixelWidth` instead. Or, as I said, go directly for `BackBufferStride`.

Comment: This code cannot survive a garbage collection.  Which will destroy the WriteableBitmap object since there are no references to that object beyond the method body, and that invalidates the pointer.  Extend the lifetime by storing it in a *static* variable or by calling GCHandle.Alloc().

Comment: @HansPassant, static variable cannot be used, as the variable is not a class member. GCHandle.Alloc() neither, as `wp` is a nonprimitive type. Can you share more specific advice on how to be sure that the GC is not destroying the data before the `Detector.setImageToDetection` function returns?

Comment: Mystifying comment.  The variable is a local variable now, that's the bug you have to fix.  GCHandle.Alloc() can only work on a nonprimitive type.  Don't set the static variable back to null or call GCHandle.Free() until you *know* that the native code is not using the pointer anymore.  Which by the sound of it you don't actually know.  The *image* variable in the C++ code is a red flag, it controls the required lifetime.

Comment: I solved it using `wb.Lock()` and `wb.Unlock()` :) As the `wb.Unlock()` is called after the  `Detector.setImageToDetection` function, the GC will not dispose it. The byte pointer `pBuff` should be pinned on the heap so now I think I'm safe :).